# Loss of convergence at end point

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Recently i have been reading "A radical approach to real analysis" by David Bressoud and this thing got stuck in my mind [image]

Here **you might lose convergence at the end point** is written in last paragraph what is this meant for an infinite trigonometric series .It has also some relation with derivatives somehow. This was written for the explanation of fourier series and crisis in mathematics but what means by phrase losing convergence and how it is related to trigonometric infinite series

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n/n^2$ converges on $[-1,1]$, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}/n$ converges on $[-1,1)$ and not on $1$. We can consider complex $x$ too. Note that when $|x|=1$, then $x^n=e^{int}=\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)$ for some $t$ and all $n$. These are trigonometric series too.

Comment: Maybe this is a naive question but i thought that an infinite series converges to one number only like exp(1) converges to 2.713 can u explain a bit how any series can converge to two different numbers? Like -1 and 1 as u mentioned

Comment: One of the 'beauties' of power series is that they converge inside the ROC, diverge outside and only the boundary remains questionable. One needs to be Abel to examine the boundary.

Comment: @Feather "converges *on* $A$" means that for all $x\in A$ the series converges, when evaluated at that $x$. Compare to saying "converges *to*".

Comment: @copper.hat can u plz recommend some a video or anything about this considering the comments and answers i feel my knowledge is very basic regarding this...

Comment: @Feather it should be in any complex analysis text.

Answer (score 1):

I think Bressoud is saying that when you switch from finite to infinite sums  of powers the worst that can happen is loss of convergence at endpoints. To see how much nastier things can get when you allow infinite sums of sines and cosines read about [pointwise convergence of Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series).